# Edge thickness in Gephi

Tags: gephi

I'm importing a .graphml file into the desktop version of gephi. In the edge data, I have a column of "distance", which I would like to display in my graph by edge thickness (so large distances are thick edges). What is the correct way to do this?

The only way I have found that comes close is if I go into the Data Labratory, and copy the distance column to the "Weight" column. But then I don't have much control anymore.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: For example, with node sizes I can apply a spline to affect sizes more dynamically, wheras the edge weights are more or less hard-coded in.

Comment: Could set Preview > Settings > Edges > Rescale weight, then adjust Thickness (one above) to match node sizes.